# SocketException when closing socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a client which continuously both sends and receives data messages which works fine, however when I close/stop the client then I get the following single line error:

> java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

Despite me closing the socket in a try-finally enclosing. Now my question is as to why I receive this error and whether or not this behavior is normal or not and how to properly handle this error. Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    
    Socket socket = null;
    
    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 9101);
         
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                while(true) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(in.readLine());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("error");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        
        System.out.println("Write to server:");
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String message = scanner.nextLine(); 

            out.println(message);
            out.flush();

        };
    } finally {
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more context for that exception. What line in your code is that exception coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to read from the socket in a separate thread even after your main thread closes the socket the other thread is still trying to read from it.

I guess a simple check-in your other thread might resolve this issue:

```
if(socket.isClosed())
   System.out.println(in.readLine());
```

I'm skeptical about the use of `isClosed` but I think it is worth trying out.